# Select where rows does not match for multiple state record entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i have the below table structure and i need help with the query

```
ID   Disp  Type   State    CreateDate
1     I5   Det     OH    1/1/2018 08:42:00
1     I5   Det     CO    1/1/2018 08:43:00
1     I5   Det     NC    1/2/2018 05:16:00
1     I5   ReDet   OH    1/3/2018 14:02:00
1     I5   ReDet   CO    1/3/2018 14:03:00
1     I5   ReDet   NC    1/3/2018 14:04:00

2     I5   Det     FL    1/4/2018 16:07:00
2     I5   ReDet   FL    1/4/2018 16:07:00

3     I5   Det     FL    1/4/2018 10:05:02
3     I5   ReDet   CA    1/4/2018 10:05:03
3     I5   ReDet   FL    1/5/2018 09:17:00
3     I5   ReDet   CA    1/6/2018 12:04:00

4     I5   Det     PA    1/7/2018 10:27:00
4     I5   Det     NE    1/8/2018 10:14:00
4     I5   Det     PA    1/8/2018 13:43:00
4     I5   ReDet   NE    1/9/2018 09:01:00
```

What i want is below:
1. For each ID that has multiple states, the Type should match the states in the order they were entered.
Ex:

```
ID 1:
OH -> Det 1st entry(1/1/2018) matches
CO -> Det 1st entry(1/1/2018) and
NC -> Det 1st entry(1/2/2018) 

And 
OH -> ReDet 2st entry(3/1/2018) matches
CO -> ReDet 2st entry(3/1/2018) and
NC -> ReDet 2st entry(3/1/2018)
```

ID 2 does not have multiple states

ID 3 - 1st entry of each state's type does not match:

```
FL -> Det 1st entry's (1/4/2018) type does not match
CA -> ReDet 1st entry(1/5/2018)
```

ID 4 - 2st entry of each state's type does not match:

```
PA -> Det   1st entry(1/7/2018) type matches
NE -> Det 1st entry(1/8/2018)
```

But

```
PA -> Det   1st entry(1/8/2018) type does not match
NE -> ReDet 1st entry(1/9/2018)
```

I want records where an ID has multiple states and the 1st,2nd, 3rd,... record type of each state does not match

As per the table the output ID's would be 3 and 4.

I have below as a starting query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tableLog AS log1
JOIN dbo.tableLog AS log2 ON log2.ID = log1.ID AND log2.state = log1.state
WHERE log1.type <> log2.type
```

but i think i am no where near for what i want.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: (3) and (4) do not match because the numbers of rows for each type are different.  That is quite different from the condition that you specify, but much simpler to find.

Comment: Assume for function's sake that (4) has both PA entries as 'Det' and both NE entries as 'ReDet'. That gives an example of the same number of rows of each type that isn't correct.

Comment: There needs to be some identity field that allows you to verify that two rows are not identical, unless you can guarantee that there will be only one entry per day.

Comment: On set (3), even if the first CA entry had been correctly 'Det', would the entries at the end of 1/5 have been correct? There would have been Det entries for both states, but only one ReDet entry.

Comment: Another control case: Set (5) has 'OR' 'Det', then 'OR' 'ReDet', Then 'WA' 'ReDet'. Is this correct, or should the first 'WA' entry be 'Det' even though an earlier 'OR' entry is 'ReDet'?

Comment: Note: QA Cases are something I'm pretty good at.

Comment: How do you know, for example, that `'OH'` came before `'CO'` for `ID = 1 AND Type = 'Det'` if both rows have equal `Date` (`1/1/2018`)?

Comment: @Stickybit, date field is datetime field.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select * into #tableLog
  from
  (             
  Select 1 AS ID ,    'I5' as Disp,   'Det' as Type,     'OH' as State ,   '1/1/2018' 
   as DteTime
  union
  Select 1 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'CO',    '1/1/2018'
  union
  Select 1 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'NC',    '1/2/2018'
  union
  Select 1 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'OH',    '1/3/2018'
  union
  Select 1 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'CO',    '1/3/2018'
  union
  Select 1 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'NC',    '1/3/2018'
  union
  Select 2 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'FL',    '1/4/2018'
  union
 Select 2 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'FL',    '1/4/2018'
 union
 Select 3 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'FL',    '1/4/2018'
 union
 Select 3 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'CA',    '1/4/2018'
  union
  Select 3 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'FL',    '1/5/2018'
  union
  Select 3 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'CA',    '1/6/2018'
  union
  Select 4 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'PA',    '1/7/2018'
  union
  Select 4 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'NE',    '1/8/2018'
  union
  Select 4 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'PA',    '1/8/2018'
   union
  Select 4 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'NE',    '1/9/2018'
 )t



Select a.rowno as row1 ,a.Type, b.rowno as row2 ,b.Type ,a.Disp,  a.State ,a. 
 [DteTime] as Datetime1,b.[DteTime] as Datetime2 from 
(
 Select ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by ID,Type order by [DteTime],State asc ) rowno, 
 * from #tableLog t1
 ) a 

inner join
(
 Select ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by ID,Type order by [DteTime] asc) rowno, * from 
 #tableLog t2
) b on a.id = b.id and a.disp = b.disp and a.State = b.State 
where a.Type ='Det' and b.type = 'ReDet'
--and a.rowno <> b.rowno 
order by a.ID,a.rowno 
drop table #tablelog
```

Comment: I can get you to a point where you can see if the position of the State is same or not , but the challenge comes in when there is sorting on dates . e.g for ID 1 you  have OH ,NC that has date as 1/1 and 1/2  when type is 'det' and same dates when  1/3 when type is 'Redet' .If you can advise me how are you going to position the states , I can get you the final query

Comment: Thanks for the query. The date field is the datetime field. So sorting by datetime field should give the states records in sequence. I should have cleared that before. I have edited the post to update some datetimes. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you want me to give the final query or you are able to manage with this?

Comment: I would really appreciate a final query as i am lost and trying to understand your query. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * into #tableLog
from
(             
 Select 1 AS ID ,    'I5' as Disp,   'Det' as Type,     'OH' as State ,   '1/1/2018 
  08:42:00' 
   as DteTime
 union
 Select 1 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'CO',    '1/1/2018 08:43:00'
 union
 Select 1 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'NC',    '1/2/2018  05:16:00'
 union
 Select 1 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'OH',    '1/3/2018 14:02:00'
 union
 Select 1 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'CO',    '1/3/2018 14:03:00'
 union
 Select 1 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'NC',    '1/3/2018 14:04:00'
  union
 Select 2 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'FL',    '1/4/2018 16:07:00'
  union
 Select 2 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'FL',    '1/4/2018 16:07:00'
 union
 Select 3 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'FL',    '1/4/2018 10:05:02'
 union
Select 3 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'CA',    '1/4/2018 10:05:03'
 union
Select 3 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'FL',    '1/5/2018 09:17:00'
 union
Select 3 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'CA',    '1/6/2018 12:04:00'
 union
Select 4 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'PA',    '1/7/2018 10:27:00'
union
Select 4 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'NE',    '1/8/2018 10:14:00'
union
Select 4 ,    'I5',   'Det',     'PA',    '1/8/2018 13:43:00'
 union
Select 4 ,    'I5',   'ReDet',   'NE',    '1/9/2018 09:01:00'
 )t





Select a.ID, a.rowno as row1 ,a.Type, b.rowno as row2 ,b.Type ,a.Disp,  a.State ,a. 
[DteTime] as Datetime1,b.[DteTime] as Datetime2 from 
 (
   Select ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by ID,Type order by [DteTime] asc ) 
   rowno, 
    * from #tableLog t1
  ) a 

 inner join
(
   Select ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by ID,Type order by [DteTime] asc) rowno, * 
  from 
#tableLog t2
) b on a.id = b.id and a.disp = b.disp and a.State = b.State 
where a.Type ='Det' and b.type = 'ReDet'
and a.rowno <> b.rowno 
order by a.ID,a.rowno 
drop table #tablelog
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Just one issue though. The type is not limited to Det and Redet. I should have made it clear. The type could be any of 5 values. I used them just as an example here.

Comment: Right now , if you can extend this solution to 5 known types , it should work.Otherwise it would need a complex query to include all the types and check the discrepancy for state records.